# How to compose mutable objects const correctly

Tags: c++, wrapper, const-correctness

`const` is required if you try to pass a reference to a temporary object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28C4239%29;k%28vs.output%29&rd=true

Which means it's not possible in C++ to model a modifiable wrapper of an object as a temporary (without being forced to make the object an lvalue):

```
inline char * PcToUnix(AutoCStringBufferA & buffer) { return PcToUnix(buffer, buffer.size()); }
inline char * PcToUnix(CStringA & str) { return PcToUnix(make_autobuffer(str)); }
```

`PcToUnix` : converts a character buffer from CR+LF to CR in-situ.
`make_autobuffer` : takes a `CString`, and locks its underlying character buffer so that we have direct access to manipulate it over the lifespan of the `autobuffer`.

So I cannot write a call statement which takes the underlying string, wraps it in a buffer management object (mutable), passes that on to a function that manipulates the contents of the buffer, and returns, unless the `autobuffer` is declared to be passed as `const &`:

WRONG:

```
inline char * PcToUnix(AutoCStringBufferA & buffer) { return PcToUnix(buffer, buffer.size()); }
```

OKAY?!

```
inline char * PcToUnix(const AutoCStringBufferA & buffer) { return PcToUnix(buffer, buffer.size()); }
```

But the "correct" form seems to be specifying a contract of: "I will not modify your buffer".  The constness here is logically correct at the level of the `autobuffer` object - it is not modified for the duration of PcToUnix() - the buffer wrapper object itself (i.e. the `autobuffer`) is not modified during `PcToUnix` - so it's true enough that it is `const`...

But, but, it is modifying its underlying object - by definition - a wrapper of something else - and that something else IS MODIFIED.

This seems to me to be a fundamental flaw with C++ `const`.  There is just no way to both satisfy the current rules (without either using non-standard compiler behavior or writing misleading API contracts or writing unnecessarily verbose code.

The verbose method:

```
inline char * PcToUnix(CStringA & str) { auto adapter = make_autobuffer(str); return PcToUnix(adapter); }
```

The misleading API method:

```
inline char * PcToUnix(const AutoCStringBufferA & buffer) { return PcToUnix(buffer, buffer.size()); }
inline char * PcToUnix(CStringA & str) { return PcToUnix(make_autobuffer(str)); }
```

If C++ offered a way to specify the constness of the wrapper as separate from the constness of the wrapped object, then we'd have the makings of a sane way to create rules and express the API succinctly.  But I just don't see how to accomplish that.

Pre-smart-pointers (or for all contexts which do not have a wrapper layer) one can specify the constness of the pointer separately from the constness of the underlying object:

```
T * const pConstPointerToMutableObject;
const T * pMutablePointerToConstObject;
const T * const pConstPointerToConstObject;
```

But there isn't any such corresponding support for wrapper objects.  There is no way to express the constness of the referer separately from the constness of the referee.  Nor any set of reasonable rules for defining or controlling the commutative/associative/distributive nature of `const`.

I don't understand why this isn't brought up constantly.  I stumble on this constantly, and find `const` to be an enormous PIA because of it.

Ideally, code should be trivially compostable - i.e. one should be able to wrapper some simpler object in another layer which adapts it in some way - maybe filters access, or adds smarts about managing subobjects, or delayed instantiation of the underlying thing, etc., so that complex and specific interfaces to ones data can be built up without having to redesign the basic object over and over - just wrap in in a layer or two that adds the necessary intelligence / logic / interface / adaptation to the context in which it is needed.

But C++ make this nigh-impossible due to const-correctness issues. (Or, I'm just too stupid to figure out how to do all of this, and in my extensive readings, I've managed to miss how it is to be done, or even that anyone is discussing these issues w/o just glossing over and ignoring this aspect of `const`).  Perhaps someone here on SO can disabuse me of whatever my mistakes are??

Comment: _"But there isn't any such corresponding support for wrapper objects."_ How about `unique_ptr<const T>`

Comment: _"`const` is required if you try to pass a reference to a temporary object."_ Start by explaining why you would want to do such a thing. And think about rvalue references.

Comment: What happens if you use the return value of `PcToUnix` after the temporary has been destroyed?

Comment: `PcToUnix` is a void function - it only creates side-effects in the char buffer that it is handed.  I realize that this rule exists to avoid situations where you're trying to modify a temporary that is then destroyed before anyone can see the side-effects.  However, for wrapper/adapter types, the side-effects are in the underlying object, not in the temporary wrapper - so disposing of it is perfectly legit, and loses nothing.

Comment: If you can give me some insight into how a `unique_ptr<>` or any other smart pointer would alleviate the problem, I'd love to hear it.  I've never figured out a way that they can be used in such circumstances.

Comment: `unique_ptr<const T>` was simply a counterexample of a wrapper object with an API which allows you to specify the constness of the referee.

Comment: The `PcToUnix` which you posted returns `char*` not `void`. How could you observe its effect on a temporary if it returned `void`?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry.  That's just a convenience / convention from C stdlib era - takes a pointer to a buffer and modifies it and returns the same pointer to aid in composition of functions.  But it doesn't create a temporary or change the value, so it's logically equivalent to void.  Sorry.

Comment: `CStringA`, `AutoCStringBufferA` are these your wrapper types? Show an example how you would want them to be used in conjunction with `PcToUnix`. It is not at all clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy approach to const correctness: **Use transitive const.**

It seems you are asking for a little too much for free *at the language level*. It's actually designed (among other things) so that you pay for what you use, and to be safe and performant. And yes, it can be very verbose.

As far as containers which are physically-const-aware, C++ is certainly capable of supporting the distinction; e.g.:

```
void A(const std::shared_ptr<const bool>& p) { /* ... */}
void B(const std::shared_ptr<bool>& p) { /* ... */}

void C() {
 A(std::make_shared<bool>(false)); // << ok
 A(std::make_shared<const bool>(false)); // << ok

 B(std::make_shared<bool>(false)); // << ok
 B(std::make_shared<const bool>(false)); // << error. API forbids removal of const.
}
```

But the C++ standard library does not provide all the containers you *might* need in order to accomplish what you are asking for.

Enumerate the smart pointer variants you would need, and consider that they are responsible for object lifetime and conversion from one container to another. Also note how much shorter that list is if you support transitive const only. Then consider the APIs in the OP would generally be converted to templates to easily support the variations.

Sometimes, you have to deal with types which have less than ideal interfaces. In those cases it's often easiest to make a container for them, and to introduce your ideal form of const.

Using this approach, the containers do the majority of the heavy lifting (=saves you from that verbosity at the call-site).

Of course, the C++-looking way to do a string conversion would look more like:

```
std::string PCToUnix(std::string pString) {
 ...mutate pString...
 return pString;
}
```

Or in place:

```
void PCToUnix(std::string& pString) {
 ...mutate pString...
}
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly and apply that to my wrapper, you're suggesting that `PcToUnix` should take a `const AutoCStringBuffer&`, because the wrapper is `const`, in the same way a `unique_ptr<>` distinguishes constness of underlying object from the smart-pointer itself.  My mistake is in trying to think of `const MyWrapper &` as implying constness of the wrapped object, which is just not what C++ is saying (or doing)?

Comment: @Mordachai I'm saying that transitive const is ideal. *transitive const* a D concept/term, most similar to C++-term *logical const*: http://dlang.org/const-faq.html#transitive-const. using transitive const, your function would be prohibited from accessing a mutable reference to (and thus mutating) the interior character buffer of a const parameter. thus, a non-const reference would be required. considering the function returns an interior pointer of its parameter, it could be unwise to pass as const because the function call may require creation of a temporary. (cont)

Comment: @Mordachai if you dislike transitive const, you are likely only a few containers/adaptors shy of accomplishing what you are after, while reducing some of your syntactical noise. an exhaustive collection of containers would be numerous. you can design these containers to be somewhat safe. using such containers, your functions would generally need to migrate to templates. the standard library does not offer all these variations of smart pointers -- just simple implementations of the most fundamental ownership models.

Comment: @Mordachai an illustration of the container variants: `template<class TCString> class AutoCStringBuffer { /* ...impl... */ };` -- then the template parameter would specify a `CString` (physical const) or a `const CString` (logical const). then `PcToUnix` would become a template, so that it supported the 3 valid type variations (and failed if the const-transitive parameter were passed as const). seems complex? consider const transitivity.

Comment: I think ideally I would have transitive const (if I understand it correctly).  That's how I intuit the situation, and what runs me afoul of C++'s non transitive const.  I really want a const MyAdapter & to consider itself as non-mutating - but then I have to deal with explcitly creating lvalues in order to achieve this.  I'm less clear on what you're saying wrt "multiple container/adapters"?  Do you mean to distinguish the constness of the underlying object in the type of the adapter (`MyConstAdapter`, `MyMutableAdapter`)?  Or...?

Comment: @Mordachai Then it becomes a matter of introducing const at the right place. At a higher level, it would be deceptive/surprising if I passed that const string to a function (`foo`) whose implementation 'corrected' the line endings. It's much less surprising to create a temporary string in `foo` if conversion is necessary, or to pass a non-const parameter if it is a mutating function. This works out nicely because the const is enforced and propagates outward when introduced -- though, it is quite viral. (cont)

Comment: @Mordachai Pretty much. I'm intentionally abstract regarding specifying such a container/adaptor only because there are many possible variations. The typical variations involved are `const`, `mutable`, pointers, values, references, ownership, single-element, and multi-element containers -- but other qualifiers and requirements exist. In reality, you can get by without all possible variants. Basic containers can be created which introduce the semantics and conversions you desire. (cont)

Comment: @Mordachai The const/mutable name is an option, but generally applies to logical const designs (because designs using physical constness have a way of transferring mutable references). I use transitive const, and I already have more containers than I would like :) But yes, it is an option to define containers which introduce semantics and conversions you use/want -- with higher safety than raw pointers/references. There have been suggestions to improve the lang/std library in these areas.